# getting “input value must be specified” error while sending graphQL query through java

Tags: java, graphql

I am trying to get some data by using graphQL. code should be in following format ,but while debugging ,i got error as following:

```
[{"message":"\"input\" value must be specified","category":"graphql-input","locations":[{"line":1,"column":10}]}]
```

Basically I want data in following format in java .

```
query { customer { id addresses { id firstname lastname street city region { region_code region region_id } postcode country_id telephone } } }
```

query i wrote in java is as following :

```
return q -> q.customerId()
            .id()   
            .firstname()
            .lastname()
            .street()
            .city()
            .region(getCustomerAddressRegionQuery())
            .postcode()
            .countryId()
            .telephone();
```

so what java query should i write in order to get the output. attached image of error here as well

Answer (score 0):

error says:
"input" value must be specified","category":"graphql-input","locations":[{"line":1,"column":10}

The problem is not in returning the value from java, the problem is with the graphql query you are performing. The query expects an input named 'input' but you are not giving it. What does your GraphQL query look like?

**If you are testing it through postman i think you should enter input data, e.g in body.**